# Custom AnnouncementListItem Visual Web Part in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010, caml

I am trying to create a visual web Part to display the latest 5 announcement list items.

I need the Announcement List Item Title to show up as a link and any attachments(only pictures) to be displayed right above it. I am planning on refreshing the web part every 15-20 minutes to be able to show the latest announcement.

I dont know how and what the best asp control and page design would be to display these items.

Here is the CAML Query with the rest of the code I have:

```
 using (SPSite oSPsite = new SPSite("http://mySharePointWebApp:Port#/"))
         {

            using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPsite.OpenWeb())
             {
                 oSPWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;

                // Fetch the List
                 SPList list = oSPWeb.Lists["Announcements"];

                SPQuery spQuery = new SPQuery();
                 //spQuery.Query = "<Where> <Eq> <FieldRef Name='Title' /> <Value           Type='Text'></Value> </Eq> </Where>";
                 spQuery.Query = "";
                 spQuery.RowLimit = 5;

                // Show item in text box
                 SPListItemCollection oListCollection = list.GetItems(spQuery);
                 foreach (ListItem oListItem in oListCollection)
                 {
                     // **What should I go with here?**
                 }

            }
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a repeater control like listbox and customize it using item templates.

```
<asp:ListBox>
    <item template>
       <div>
         <image control/>
         <text control/>
       </div>
    </item template>
</asp:ListBox>
```

To get the latest 5 announcements, write CAML SPQuery to get top 5 items by ID in descending order. 
Check to see if an attachment exist for the announcement. If it does then get the attachment URL and check if it is an image type by looking at the extension.

If image exist then assign the attachment relative url to the image control in the item template. For announcements with no image you can choose to either hide the image control or assign URL to some common image.

You can also use [Linq to SharePoint](http://www.zimmergren.net/technical/sp-2010-getting-started-with-linq-to-sharepoint-in-sharepoint-2010) to get the latest 5 announcements. Code should look like this

```
var top5Announcements = (From a in siteDataContext.Announcements OrderBy a.id descending select a).Take(5)
```

Comment: Hey Ken thanks for the input. Im real new to programming though and was wondering if you could expand a little more on how I would actually databind the linq or CAML query to the listbox control.